# How do I put a 'Sales Notice' popup showing recent sales on WP?

Tags: html, wordpress, plugins

I was wondering if anyone knew how to put a box in the corner showing recent sales of products on a site (or if there was a plugin for this on Wordpress) - On the code its shown as 'salesnotice' but I cannot find it as a plugin anywhere.

Example:

www.kogan.com.au - the bottom left corner shows the product that was bought not long ago. The box also shows different products and fades in/out.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a perfect situation to use a widget. Create a widget that queries for the most recently bought product and display that post's information. Then once the widget is set up define an area on the page you want it to show. If you want it on every page then footer.php would probably suffice. Hope this helps!